# using Teechart activeX in MFC with multithreading crashed

Tags: multithreading, activex, teechart

When I use the teechart to display the curves in a user thread in MFC, it crashed.I want to know  wheter this activeX can support the multithread.

Answer (score 1):

TeeChart isn't thread safe, so you should prevent the chart to be repainted from one thread and modified from another thread at the same time.

Comment: Thank you very much. I couldn't find a demo using Teechart in multithread. @Yeray